# How to use QPainter with QgsMapCanvasItem

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm trying to plot (superimposed) a rectangle plus some text on the QGIS map canvas, which already has several layers. A similar situation but for a circle is feasible by subclassing `QgsMapCanvasItem`:

```
class CircleCanvasItem(QgsMapCanvasItem):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        super().__init__(canvas)
        self.center = QgsPoint(0, 0)
        self.size = 100

    def setCenter(self, center):
        self.center = center

    def center(self):
        return self.center

    def setSize(self, size):
        self.size = size

    def size(self):
        return self.size

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(self.center.x() - self.size/2,
        self.center.y() - self.size/2,
        self.center.x() + self.size/2,
        self.center.y() + self.size/2)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(self.center.x(), self.center.y());
        path.arcTo(self.boundingRect(), 0.0, 360.0)
        painter.fillPath(path, QColor("green"))
```

However, trying to write something similar but using `QPainter` (instead of `QPainterPath`)

```
class RectangleCanvasItem(QgsMapCanvasItem):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        super().__init__(canvas)
        
    def setCenter(self, center):
        self.center = center

    def center(self):
        return self.center

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.drawRect(100, 100, 300, 150)
```

results in the error message:

> Painter not active

Looking at some examples with `QPainter`, it seems that `QPainter` is initialized with some image (e.g. `QPainter_instance.begin(image_name)`). I was wondering if anyone has any suggestion on how to use `QPainter` with `QgsMapCanvasItem` or maybe an alternative method to approach the problem.

Comment: the first argument of `paint` method is a `QPainter` object. Just use that one. No need to initialize a new one :)

Comment: Thanks! The solution was right in front of my own eyes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I add my [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456722/how-to-use-qpainter-with-qgsmapcanvasitem#comment745666_456722) as answer:

The first argument of [`QgsMapCanvasItem::paint`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvasItem.html#a6e56fdf9339bb1dfa3c347f2a4d014c) method is a `QPainter` instance which is already initialized to paint on the correct scene.

Therefore this will work:

```
class RectangleCanvasItem(QgsMapCanvasItem):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        super().__init__(canvas)

    def setCenter(self, center):
        self.center = center

    def center(self):
        return self.center

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.drawRect(100, 100, 300, 150) 
        
        
rect_item = RectangleCanvasItem(iface.mapCanvas())
iface.mapCanvas().scene().addItem(rect_item)
```

Comment: The rectangle is already added when the line rect_item = RectangleCanvasItem(iface.mapCanvas()) is executed.
When the line iface.mapCanvas().scene().addItem(rect_item) is executed, the following error is displayed "Qt: QGraphicsScene::addItem: item has already been added to this scene"